# How do I get a "git log" patch for a specific commit

Tags: git, version-control, patch, git-log

If I have a commit hash that has not yet been pushed to origin, how can I generate a patch for that commit only.  I would like to use `git log -p --no-names` but can't see a switch to pass in a specific commit hash. Should I be using a different git command?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For git log patch:

```
git log -p -1 <commit>
```

You should be using `git format-patch` for patches though:

```
git format-patch -1 <commit>
```

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html

Comment: thanks.  what's the benefit of format-patch instead of `git log -p`?

Comment: @Jonathan: Both suffice as a diff intended to be consumed by a human (e.g. for review), but the output of `git format-patch` encapsulates the author information and the commit message (as well as the diff text) in a standard format  so that it can be reliably parsed by other tools (e.g. `git send-email` to send them as emails and `git am` to apply one or more patches (e.g. some that have been collected as received emails)).

Comment: thanks @Chris that's helpful.  it seems that ubuntu patch is having issues parsing the output of `git log -p` so that might be the solution

Comment: @Jonathan: Git-style diffs (i.e. those with a `diff --git` header) have several extensions that regular *patch* will not understand (the format is very similar though, so it may work in many cases). You can apply plain diffs (e.g. from `git diff` or `git log -p`) with `git apply` (even outside the working tree of a repository), or if you have full “patches” from `git format-patch`, you can use `git am` to (re)create the represented commits.